# How to prevent an unauthorized node from joing a Cassandra cluster?

Tags: cassandra, nosql

How is security handled between Cassandra seeds and nodes? ie. How to prevent unauthorized replication of my datacenter by posing as my node?  I could create a firewall with a whitelist, but is there another mechanism as well?

Comment: often it makes sense to have two different interfaces, one for inter-cluster communication (ports 7000 or 7001), and another - for client communication.  And limit inter-cluster to specific network, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enabling [node-to-node SSL](https://docs.datastax.com/en/security/6.7/security/secInternodeSsl.html) solves this issue.  Essentially, a false node pretending to be legit shouldn't have a matching Java Truststore, and will thus be denied from joining the cluster.